# Change a specific line using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, quoting

I need to change a line in a Java file called `DbConnection.java` using the `sed` command.
The line is:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://**localhost**/**bajaj**","**root**", "**root**");
```

I have tried the below which works fine (I can replace user provided value):

```
sed -i "s|://localhost/bajaj|://${HOSTNAME}/${DBNAME}|" DbConnection.java
```

But the below one I need to get to work, I can't replace the `DBUSERNAME` & `DBPASSWORD`:

```
sed -i "s|"jdbc:mysql://localhost/bajaj","root", "root"|"jdbc:mysql://${HOSTNAME}/${DBNAME}","${DBUSERNAME}", "${DBPASSWORD}"|" DbConnection.java
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using double quotes to delimit the string as well as inside the string itself, so the quoted string stops early and your internal quote characters aren't included:

```
sed -i "s|"jdbc:mysql:...
Ends here-^
```

You can escape each of the quotes inside the string:

```
sed -i "s|\"jdbc:mysql://localhost/bajaj\",\"root\", \"root\"|\"jdbc:mysql://${HOSTNAME}/${DBNAME}\",\"${DBUSERNAME}\", \"${DBPASSWORD}\"|" DbConnection.java
```

Now, each double quote inside the `sed` command has a backslash before it, to stop the shell from interpreting it.

Alternatively, you can use single quotes around the `sed` argument:

```
sed -i 's|"jdbc:mysql://localhost/bajaj","root", "root"|"jdbc:mysql://'"${HOSTNAME}"'/'"${DBNAME}"'","'"${DBUSERNAME}"'", "'"${DBPASSWORD}"'"|' DbConnection.java
```

In order to have the variables still be replaced, we're leaving single quotedness around each variable: `'AB'"$VAR"'CD'`. We double-quote the variables in the shell to stop them being expanded into multiple words.